# How to use email dynamic list to SNS Topic Subscription in AWS CloudFormation?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-sns

**My templaste is (for one emeil):**

```
  Parameters:
    MailAlarmsSNS:
       Type: String
       Default: mymail@company.com

  MessagesInErrorTopic:
    Type: AWS::SNS::Topic
    Properties:
      TopicName: foo
      DisplayName: This topic is used to send an email
      Subscription:
        - Endpoint: !Ref MailAlarmsSNS
          Protocol: email
```

I want use a dynamic list input (comma separated)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only do that using [custom resource](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-custom-resources.html) or a [macro](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-macros.html) that you would have to develop yourself in the form of lambda functions.

Comment: thank you for these two links to documentation. Do you have a link to a similar example on SNS?

Comment: Here's an example of specifically using a custom resource to create multiple sns subscriptions: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/prescriptive-guidance/latest/patterns/subscribe-multiple-email-endpoints-to-an-sns-topic-by-using-a-custom-resource.html

Answer (score 1):

As stated by @Marcin, you typically need to use a custom resource or macro for that. This [repository](https://github.com/chandrahaswtw/aws-sns-multiple-subscription-creation) gives you complete code using the custom resource to add multiple endpoints.

Answer (score 0):

You can give multiple endpoints in a single SNS Topic like below:

[image: Cloudformation template for multiple emails]

Comment: sorry, is it a wrong answer. You don not have a list but just 2 elements (not x elements).